# SQL reporting active users and logins

Tags: mysql, sql, database, reporting-services

I have a SQL Table of logins as a data source, and each row has an id, timestamp and user_id.

Similar to this:

| id | timestamp | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01T15:17:13.000Z | 234 |
| 2 | 2022-01-02T15:17:13.000Z | 235 |

I want to build a report that shows an aggregate of logins by year. So something like (for all months, just using January as an example.):

| Year | Active Users in January | Logins in January |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019 | 500 | 10000 |
| 2020 | 600 | 10002 |

Essentially, the active users would be grouping the rows of logins by user_id, and the logins would just aggregate the timestamps by month.

Is this kind of view something I build using a SQL query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use aggregation here:

```sql
SELECT
    YEAR(timestamp) AS Year,
    COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS `Active Users in January`,
    COUNT(*) AS `Logins in January`
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    MONTH(timestamp) = 1
GROUP BY
    YEAR(timestamp);
```

The number of active users is given by the distinct count of users for a given year, in the month of January.  The number of logins is just the number of entries for a given year in January.

If you want to report for all months and all years, then use:

```sql
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%Y-%m') AS ym,
    COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS `Active Users per month`,
    COUNT(*) AS `Logins in month`
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY 1;
```

Comment: Thank you! Would I be able to do that for multiple months in a single query?

Comment: Yes...but that's a different query and a different question, not what you asked.  Use `GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%Y-%m')`, and then also select that instead of `YEAR(timestamp)`.  Then, remove the `WHERE` clause as well since you want all months.